# Does mypy==x give the same error messages for all Python versions?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm the maintainer of pypdf. We use a CI that currently checks mypy for Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12.

I am thinking about just running mypy for one Python version.

Does mypy in a fixed version x behave the same for all Python versions (we do have pytest covering the code; meaning if we import stuff that is not available in one version pytest will fail).

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I've always just run mypy on the latest Python version available without any issues I can think of. (I'm the maintainer of babel.)

Comment: That depends on if you’re pinning mypy. If not, older Python versions get dropped (I don’t believe there’s a version which supports both Python 3.6 and Python 3.12??), and newer mypy versions fix uncaught bugs in older ones.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM That doesn't matter if you're using `from __future__ import annotations`.

Comment: @dROOOze Thats what I meant by mypy==x. Of course different versions of mypy behave different. I'm asking for a pinned version - but not a specific version.

Comment: I think I got a bit confused because you were talking about a mypy which runs everything from Python 3.6 to Python 3.12, but now looking over the mypy packaging files, they don't seem to specify a maximum version of Python, so I'm guessing you'll just be running the latest mypy which supports Python 3.6.

Comment: No, it won't give same outputs: e.g. `enum.member` will be error below 3.10, and `collections.Sequence` or `import formatter` will be error on and above 3.10. `mypy` is aware of python internal and stdlib changes and analyses your code accordingly.